# interpolation method to Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I asked about the compact trace embedding ([trace embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380137/trace-embedding)). In the answer,

For $N \ge3,$

- trace map $W^{1,2}(\Omega) \to W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega)$ is bounded,
- inclusion $W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega) \to L^1(\partial \Omega)$ is compact,
- inclusion $W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega) \to L^{q^*}(\partial \Omega)$ with $q^* = \frac{2(N-1)}{N-2}$ is bounded.

**By interpolation, the inclusion $W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega) \to L^{q}(\partial \Omega)$ is compact for all $q \in [1,q^*)$, and the claim follows.**

The only modification needed in the case $N=2$ is that this time $W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega) \to L^{q}(\partial \Omega)$ is bounded for all $q<q^*=\infty$, but not for $q=q^*$. This is because the Sobolev embedding doesn't work if $\textrm{order of derivatives} \times \textrm{exponent} = \textrm{dimension}$. The claim follows in the same fashion.

I don't understand the part **"By interpolation, the inclusion $W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega) \to L^{q}(\partial \Omega)$ is compact for all $q \in [1,q^*)$"** .

Would you tell me about it in detail? I would be grateful for any comment about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{f_n\}$ be given, such that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $W^{1/2,2}(\partial\Omega)$.
We have to show $\| f_n - f\|_{L^q(\partial\Omega)} \to 0$.

By Hölder's inequality, we have
$$
\| f_n - f \|_{L^q(\partial\Omega)}
\le
\| f_n - f \|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)}^{\lambda}\,
\| f_n - f \|_{L^{q^*}(\partial\Omega)}^{1-\lambda},
$$
where $\lambda \in (0,1)$ is determined by $1/q = \lambda/1 + (1-\lambda)/q^*$.
This inequality is typically called an 'interpolation inequality, because you can interpolate between the norms in $L^1$ and $L^{q^*}$.

Now, since the embedding to $L^1$ is compact, you have
$$
\| f_n - f \|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)} \to 0
$$
and since the embedding to $L^{q^*}$ is bounded, you have
$$
\| f_n - f \|_{L^{q^*}(\partial\Omega)} \le C
$$
for some $C > 0$.

Putting things together, you have the desired 
$\| f_n - f\|_{L^q(\partial\Omega)} \to 0$.